# Unity build fail to run landscape on one plus mobile phones

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, landscape

Hie,
My game is running landscape full screen on all devices except some mobile phones like "One plus 7t " etc

Here is the player settings screenshot, if anyone can help me with this issue it would be great.

[Please Click here to see Player Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI0kJ.png)

I have tried to build with all the latest Unity editors and am still not able to run the game landscape in one plus mobile phones.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening with more details? Does it crash? Have you looked at the logs with logcat?

Comment: @RetiredNinja have mentioned that on "One Plus" mobile phones game doesn't run in landscape mode, for reference have attached a screenshot of Unity player settings.

Comment: Does that mean it runs correctly but in portrait mode? "doesn't run" could mean many things.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes game running properly but it runs in portrait instead of landscape mode.